How Can I Ensure Reliable SPL Token Transfers in Python and Address Intermittent Failures by Adding a Priority Fee?
I'm trying to implment spl token transfer in TG bot in python, but the transfer is failing from time to time with quite delay, I guess I could put priority fee to improve the situation, but cannot figure out how to do this in my current approach.
sharing the code below
# Fetch the sender's balance
        balance = spl_client.get_balance(sender_token_account).value.amount

        # Adjust the amount if necessary
        adjusted_amount = min(int(float(amount) * pow(10, decimals)), int(balance))

        recent_blockhash = client.get_latest_blockhash().value.blockhash

        transaction = spl_client.transfer(
            source=sender_token_account,
            dest=dest_token_account,
            owner=sender_keypair,
            amount=adjusted_amount,
            multi_signers=None,
            opts=TxOpts(
                skip_preflight=True, preflight_commitment="finalized"
            ),
            recent_blockhash=recent_blockhash,
        )

        # return transaction
        confirmation = client.confirm_transaction(
            transaction.value, commitment="finalized"
        )

        if confirmation.value:
            if confirmation.value[0].err is None:
                return transaction
            else:
                print(f"Transaction failed with error: {confirmation.value[0].err}")
                return "error"
        else:
            return "error"

I'd appreciate any advice about this issue, or any lead to resoucrces that I can reference.
I could not find answer in this link which specified in the notice.
Thanks!
